# USB WiFi is detected but can't connect

Tags: wireless, networking, usb, network-manager, realtek

I have recently purchased a USB WiFi adapter with a Realtek chipset for my netbook. Network-manager detects it well enough and can see my home WiFi network too, but when I try connecting I am just prompted endlessly for the WPA password, as if connection is somehow rejected or fails (I am using the right password).

A series of info about my network setup can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/CzA2ZkNp). The relevant network interface is `wlan1`.

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: 80:c0:b0:70:e0:20
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=3.0.0-13-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:3308 D-Link Corp.
```

What might be the issue or how do I troubleshoot it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you have the right WPA version(WPA, WPA2) or Encryption protocol(TKIP,CCMP/AES).

Comment: I have two WiFi adapters, wlan0 (built-in) and wlan1 (USB). wlan0 uses the auto-detected protocol and it connects. wlan1 also uses the auto-detected protocol but it does not connect.

Where can I check what protocol the respective network interfaces use? Thanks.

Comment: Is there MAC address filtering on the Wifi, i.e. a specific device with a specific hardware address is allowed to connect, but another isnt?

Comment: Not one that I have configured, but maybe there is a default? Is there a way I can check it?

Answer (score 1):

try downgrading the security of your wifi network. If its a lousy reverse engineering of the driver. It might not support more modern  / secure wifi modes like WPA2