# WiFi is slower than in Windows

Tags: wireless, centrino

The built-in WiFi network adapter in my netbook works fine in Windows, but in Ubuntu it is much slower, to the point where the web is hardly usable. Why might this be?

I've tried using an external WiFi adapter instead, but [without luck](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84599/usb-wifi-is-detected-but-cant-connect).

I've posted my network info [here](http://pastebin.com/CzA2ZkNp).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with *iwlagn*, because it disables *n* on your built-in wifi adapter.
This post on ubuntu forums should solve your problem:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9953554&postcount=5